# Angular 2 - Multiple routes for the same component without re-instantiates?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to use multiple routes for the same component without re-instantiates.

Example routes:

```
[
  { path: 'test/:p1', component:component },
  { path: 'test/:p1/:p2', component:component },
  { path: 'test/:p1/:p2/:p3', component:component }
]
```

When i switch between paths component is re-instantiates and resolvers are run again. I remind that don't want to use query params.

My case is precisely described in this issue:
[Optional Parameters for angular2 routes #12347](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12347)

Any ideas? Do I need to use query params?

My resolver code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<MyObject[]> {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<MyObject[]> {
    return this.myService.getData(route.params.id);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the issue with resolvers being run again ? Is it about some HTTP requests that are fired again ?
There doesn't seem to be any update on this issue, so I believe only a workaround can be found for this solution yet. 

What you could do, is in your resolver to watch for the current route / next route to be activated, so that it doesn't fire the requests if you are already coming from a path which containt your component. That could be one solution

Comment: Even when i coming from a path which contains my component is re-instantiates (my resolver get http request).

Comment: Can you show your resolver code and component constructor / ngOnInit ?

Comment: Resolver return observable from data service and ngOnInit subscribe data from activated route - just it.

Comment: Please add your resolver code. This is the only thing that needs to be changed in order to avoid doing an extra http call.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet sorry for the late reply. I added resolver to question.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that work ? It's more of a workaround than a real solution, but that's the best I can come up with :

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<MyObject[]> | null {
  if (route.includes('test')) {
    return null;
  }

  return this.myService.getData(route.params.id);
}
```

And then you could also manage this case in your component, where you avoid doing anything in case your resolvers returns `null`.

Comment: Very thanks for idea, but I'm looking for best practices. For now I'd redesigned routes architecture and have few route children that shared data.

Comment: Either this is a real complex case or there is an architectural problem underlying... I don't think you can do anything else than that for that issue in the resolver.

Another solution would be storing the observable of the HTTP request to serve it again (and thus avoiding re-doing the call if it's available). Your next issue would be to manage when to clear this stored observable to actually update the data fetched.

Comment: When I have route children data isn't resolve again when i change children routes, only when i initialize parent.

Comment: Yes, because your parent route is already reached. The `resolve()` occurs only when the main route changed (event if the same component is reached)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround using a [URLMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher):

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  matcher: urlSegments => 
    urlSegments[0] && urlSegments[0].path === 'test' ? {
      consumed: urlSegments,
      posParams: {
        ...urlSegments[1] && {p1: urlSegments[1]},
        ...urlSegments[2] && {p2: urlSegments[2]},
        ...urlSegments[3] && {p3: urlSegments[3]}
      }
    } :
    null,
  component: component
}];
```